# Generating IOS iPA file on server side with new assets and bundle id

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, continuous-integration

**App functionality -** I have created an event based application named (ABC) which is a product of client, so if the customer of ABC want to organise an event, they can register there event with app (ABC) or they can ask for a new app (which generally will be a clone of abc) with some customisation.

**What we do -** for this we just create a clone of base code and do some changes in each clone. below are the changes we do in each clone.

1- app icon, app name, app splash , Facebook id, LinkedIn id, Twitter key, Urban-airship key , bundle id, certificates, event id.

Here i want to mention that each clone will be live from different developer account.

Whenever new clone requirement came we do all these thing manually in xCode and then create the build for client testing and then share the diawi link with client for testing.

**What i want to do -** So we just want to add some automation on it, i want to put up base code or ipa of base code on server, now whenever the new app requirement came, we will give client an option on cms to upload all the required detail which is required for new clone like (app icon, app name, app splash , Facebook id, LinkedIn id, Twitter key, Urban-airship key , bundle id, certificates, event id) and when he will submit the details we just need to build the app on server and want to download the new ipa with news assets and details, so that client can install the app for testing.

**Question -** is this possible to upload all the detail from CMS and build the project on server side with new uploaded data. if yes then what process we have to follow?

Comment: Theoretically yes, that is possible, everything *you* can do with the project and Xcode the computer can do with just command line calls as well. Are you running a Mac OS server?

Comment: Hi @luk2302 thanks for response, right-now we have not setup any server but if we will put up the code on server it will be MAC OS server. but my question is what process we will flow for all this.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer:

online continuous integration + fastlane

## Long answer:

This is quite possible but you need a continuous integration system, like circleci or jenkins or bitrise.

For example on bitrise you can create an app, linked on a git repository. Every build can be triggered:

- manually
- on a special git event (a tag for example)
- hourly/daily/weekly ... etc
- on a incoming webhook with special arguments

This last possibility can be your solution (but need some work).

What I see, in a brief (and not complete chain):

- on server side, client push/create a new app with all assets needed
- `Webhook` is triggered with these ids/assets/urls
- `CircleCi/Bitrise` triggers a build with these datas
- a `script` is triggered, not a circle ci build to launch `Fastlane`

  - much more efficient and customizable
- fastlane triggers the given `lane` with all these data like this:

```
fastlane -iOS -lane build -fbid _XX_ -twid _YY_ -appicon _IC_ -bundleIdentifier __BUNDLEID__
```

Thanks to `fastlane`, you can easily:

- Rebuild a project from a "whitelabelized" app
- Generate assets (ie your splash and app icon)
- Communicate to your developer account to create app (app id, provisioning profile)
- Build app on a different scheme, and/or with different bundle identifier
- Generate archive
- post your adchoc/appstore app on TestFlight, or epicenter, or event on CircleCI new testing platform
- Automatically post a review of this app

Some links:

https://www.bitrise.io

https://circleci.com

https://fastlane.tools

My holy bible:

https://docs.fastlane.tools

Your idea is ambitious but, with some work can be fully done !
Enjoy !

Julien

Comment: Hi @jlngdt thanks for your answer, we want that developer should not be involved whenever new clone requirement came, because base code will be same for all the apps.  but in continuous integration we have to manually change bundle id , assets and other detail and then we have to push the code on respective repository right? once i will commit and push the code then project will be build. please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: not manually, fastlane can handle this for you. It's a bit of work about understand how fastlane works but, trust me, this work will pay. check the documentation about seting up and  `fastlane build`:

https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/

https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/build_ios_app/#build_ios_app